# Swift 5.2 and UnsafePointer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, assembly

In Swift 5.2, there is an issue that triggers UB for using `UnsafePointer`. ( https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA/issues/183 and https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/415437#415437 )

I would like to know why it happened and what changes trigger this issue, though I am not an expert on LLVM nor swift.

After searching, https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/27695 emits new warnings about `unsound pointer conversions` but I don't understand what it means.

Consider this code that triggers warning on Swift 5.2:

```
import Foundation

func copy(items: Array<UInt8>) -> Data {
    puts("Hello")
    // First version, using UnsafePointer conversion
    let result = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(items), count: items.count)
    // Second version, without UnsafePointer
   // let result = Data(items)
    puts("World")
    return result
}
```

In https://godbolt.org/z/jq8KZN , with optimization enabled, the second version calls the constructor of (Foundation)Data with surrounded by `swift_retain` / `swift_release` pair. However, the first version doesn't have such codes:

First Version:

```
    lea     rdi, [r13 + 32]
    mov     rsi, qword ptr [r13 + 16]
    add     rsi, rdi
    call    ($s10Foundation4DataV15_RepresentationOyAESWcfCTf4nd_n)
    mov     r12, rax
```

Second Version:

```
    mov     rdi, r13
    call    swift_retain@PLT
    lea     rdi, [rip + ($sSays5UInt8VGMD)]
    call    __swift_project_boxed_opaque_existential_1
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax]
    lea     r12, [rax + 32]
    mov     r14, qword ptr [rax + 16]
    add     r14, r12
    mov     rdi, r13
    call    swift_retain@PLT
    mov     rdi, r12
    mov     rsi, r14
    call    ($s10Foundation4DataV15_RepresentationOyAESWcfCTf4nd_n)
    mov     r14, rax
    mov     r12, rdx
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1
    mov     rdi, r13
    call    swift_release@PLT
```

How can I interpret these differences?